MacOS points to old tkinter gives blank screen
This seems to be a perennial question about getting MacOS to point to the correct version of tkinter. I have a very simple python script that draws to the canvas from geeksforgeeks.
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
C = Canvas(root, bg="yellow",height=250, width=300)
line = C.create_line(108, 120,320, 40,fill="green")
arc = C.create_arc(180, 150, 80, 210, start=0,extent=220,fill="red")
oval = C.create_oval(80, 30, 140,150, fill="blue")
C.pack()
mainloop()

When I run it,
-> python tkTest2.py

it draws the window but it's blank and gives the dreaded terminal error:
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.

Clicking in the window gives:
2024-11-26 15:16:47.379 python[29220:77343080] +[IMKClient subclass]: chose IMKClient_Modern
2024-11-26 15:16:47.379 python[29220:77343080] +[IMKInputSession subclass]: chose IMKInputSession_Modern

I've yet to find an answered question that solves my problem. I deleted my pyenv and tcl-tk brew installs and reinstalled per these instructions.
-> brew install tcl-tk
==> Caveats
==> tcl-tk
The sqlite3_analyzer binary is in the `sqlite-analyzer` formula.
-> brew install python-tk@3.10 
==> Caveats
==> python-tk@3.10
python-tk@3.10 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.
-> brew install pyenv
-> pyenv install 3.10.15                                                                                                                                   master
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.10.15.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.15/Python-3.10.15.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.10.15...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Installed Python-3.10.15 to /Users/johnkomp/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15
-> pyenv versions                                                                                                                                          master
  system
* 3.10.15 (set by /Users/johnkomp/Programming/git/Stochastic-Games/RL-Apps/.python-version)
-> pyenv local 3.10.15                                                                                                                                     master
-> pyenv global 3.10.15 

From that feedback I'd suspect that it built correctly using the newer tcl/tk from homebrew.
My PATH is:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tcl-tk/9.0.0_1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/mike/.local/bin:/Users/mikesmith/.pyenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin

Yet if I run this simple script:
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
print(root.tk.exprstring('$tcl_library'))
print(root.tk.exprstring('$tk_library'))    
print(tkinter.TkVersion)

I get:
-> python tkTest.py
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts
/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts
8.5
/Users/mikesmith/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/bin/python

-> which python
/Users/mikesmith/.pyenv/shims/python

so it's obviously still pointing to the old versions. What can possibly still be pointing there? Do I have to rebuild the framework? And how does one do that?

You need to show exactly how you ran your script. And also print sys.executable so we know which Python you are running.

I updated my description to add how the scripts were run. Does this help?

I was experiencing issues similar to yours while running a Python program on my MacBook. Additionally, due to these errors, I could not view the buttons I created for my Tkinter GUI once I completed the following.
Error:


2024-12-14 10:16:16.092 Python[89542:11677896] +[IMKClient subclass]: chose IMKClient_Modern
2024-12-14 10:16:16.092 Python[89542:11677896] +[IMKInputSession subclass]: chose IMKInputSession_Modern



Actions performed:


brew uninstall python



Reinstalled Python through the Python website
https://www.python.org/downloads/
After running through the installation prompt, I could view the buttons for my calculator project successfully. Let me know if this helps; thanks!
